# Need to add a class to hide and show element once active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery. I have a sidebar menu with a class "sidebar-mini" (attached to the  element) "sidebar-collapse" "sidebar-open" are classes added upon toggle. But I just need to add a class to hide and display a logo attached to the sidebar once it collapses to make the UX more efficient. I tried countless codes but no solution. Please help.

I target the sidebar, logo to hide

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar-mini');
var logo = $('.sidebar-logo');
var sidebarcollapse = $('.sidebar-collapse');
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse') ) {
      $('.sidebar-logo').addClass('hide-logo');
    }
  });
```

...

I tried this too
...

```
if($('.sidebar-collpase').length > 0) {
  logo.addClass('hide-logo');
} else {}
```

...

...

```
if ($(sidebarCollapse == true)) {

 logo.addClass('hide-logo');
} else {
 logo.removeClass('hide-logo');
}
```

...

The css I intend to hide logo and display

```
// HIDE SIDEBAR-LOGO AND DISPLAY
.hide-logo {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.display-logo {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your HTML and CSS too.

Comment: The sidebar is a custom sidebar menu AdminLte. Will there be any code in particular you might want to see to help me out?

Comment: *logo attached to the sidebar* - how attached?  is it inside the element you add/remove `sidebar-open` to/from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.display-logo {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
} 
/*Add This CSS*/
.sidebar-collapse .display-logo
{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just toggle the logo's display by adding another function say, `checkBody()` that checks the body class list whenever you run the function that toggles the side menu of yours.

In the following example, I will use a div as a dummy representation of the logo and a button as a dummy representative of the side-menu being hidden or shown:

```js
function checkBody(){
  if ( $('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse') ) {
    $('.sidebar-logo').addClass('hide-logo');
  } else {
    $('.sidebar-logo').removeClass('hide-logo');
  }
};

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('body').toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
  checkBody();
})
```

```css
.sidebar-logo {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #FFF;
}
.hide-logo {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- dummy elements -->

<div class="sidebar-logo">LOGO</div>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Just add the `checkBody` function outside the function that toggles your side-bar and add a reference to that function `checkBody();` like I did in the click listener function inside the function that toggles your side-bar.

The click listener function above represents the function that toggles your side-bar menu.